# defining functions with keyword arguments

Tags: racket

Are there advantages in defining function arguments as keywords rather than just normal arguments? Was hoping to find the answer on http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use keywords arguments when

```
- there are a lot of arguments
- most arguments have default arguments
```

For a function with, say, 10 arguments it can be difficult to remember the order of the argument. When keywords are used, then the order doesn't matter.